# Get date formatted field values from JSON using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below is my JSON

```
[{"oppname":"BHP Deepwater Invictus returns to Tinidad","account":"BHP Petroleum (Trinidad 2C) Ltd.","contact":"Berky Ashcraft","title":"Sr. Drilling Engineer","doi":"2018-11-07","country_c":"Trinidad and Tobago","11-2018":"0","10-2018":"0","09-2018":"0","08-2018":"0","07-2018":"0","06-2018":"0","05-2018":"0","04-2018":"0","03-2018":"0","02-2018":"0","01-2018":"0","12-2017":"0"}]
```

As you can see I have some fields in the format of date ("11-2018" etc). How can I get these values in the front end AJAX call? I can get other values like this.oppname or this.account etc but this.11-08 doesn't work, neither this.(11-08). What is the proper way of getting these kind of field values?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

To access the key which has `-` you need to use following pattern

```
this["11-2018"]
```

Comment: This has been answered many times on SO. Please mark the question as duplicate instead.

Comment: @31piy sure I am going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ECMAscripts "bracket notation":

```js
var testData= [{"oppname":"BHP Deepwater Invictus returns to Tinidad","account":"BHP Petroleum (Trinidad 2C) Ltd.","contact":"Berky Ashcraft","title":"Sr. Drilling Engineer","doi":"2018-11-07","country_c":"Trinidad and Tobago","11-2018":"0","10-2018":"0","09-2018":"0","08-2018":"0","07-2018":"0","06-2018":"0","05-2018":"0","04-2018":"0","03-2018":"0","02-2018":"1","01-2018":"0","12-2017":"0"}];

console.log(testData[0]["09-2018"]);
console.log(testData[0]["02-2018"]);
```

[Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: This has been answered many times on SO. Please mark the question as duplicate instead.

Comment: @31piy marked as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
var jsonData = {"11-2018":"0","10-2018":"0","09-2018":"0","08-2018":"0","07-2018":"0","06-2018":"0","05-2018":"0","04-2018":"0","03-2018":"0","02-2018":"0","01-2018":"0","12-2017":"0"};


console.log(Object.keys(jsonData));

Object.keys(jsonData).map(function(arr) {
  console.log(jsonData[arr]);
})
```